# ServletHttpRequest.getRequestUrl lost port number

Tags: java, apache, tcp, jboss

We use JBoss 4.2.2.GA (served at port `7001`) and Apache http server as front end (served at
port `9999`)

when I visit `xxx.xxx.com:9999` the `request.getRequestUrl()` does not return the port number.

How could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please see how the Apache http server is sending the request to JBoss appserver . I am guessing it is masking the call by skipping port and calling `xxx.xxx.com/xz/` directly.

You can still get the original URL as it may be recorded in HTTP header as `Referer`

Monitor the traffic in apache http server to understand it clearly.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#accesslog