# Why is Apache https server is not sending the Port# in the URL?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, amazon-web-services

I have a secure(https:443) application Running on Amazon Web services(`AWS`) have TOmcat7 and Apache http server to it.The URL looks like this https://ama.its.com/service. This works perfectly.

Their is a new requirement for cost effective alternative to run the `development AWS instances` of our Application on a non-standard ssl port like `"23456"`. So the URL now becomes https://ama.its.com:23456/service. I have a Servlet implementation in our code. When i do a `"request.getRequestURL().toString();"`it returns the URL with out Port# `https://ama.its.com/service`. This is causing problems for my application. I want the URL to include the port# in it.

I googled on this a bit i saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149163/servlethttprequest-getrequesturl-lost-port-number). The Post tells that Apache server is masking the PORT and reconstructing the URL with out port. The post suggested a work around for getting the URL from the Request header, but i don't want to go that route now until i find out if their is a fix for it. I also looked in the Apache http logs if something funny is going on their. i couldn't find out anything suspicious.

Is their any way i can tell the server not to exclude the Port# in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is something buggy with Apache HTTP server when using  a non standard ssl Port other that 443. When the URL is being sent the Port is stripped out in the request object. Alternatively getting the URL from the Request Header is a good option.

That option did not fit my needs as i have one website to the user but the Content i displayed in the Iframe of the website is actually loading the data on a different tomcat (Which is AWS server). So basically  the request header gave the URL of the main URL than the URL of the website running inside of the iframe.

I have a workaround that fits to my project need to store the URL of the website with in the IFrame to get from a properties file and use it .